# In what order to upgrade skills to: Ajax, Spring MVC, and JSF 2.0?

Tags: ajax, jsf, spring-mvc

I am Jr. Java MVC programmer whose current skill set is:

1. Core Java
2. MVC
3. JSP

Corporate directive is to upgrade to:

1. Spring MVC
2. AJAX
3. JSF 2.0

What is the best order in which to learn these new technologies?  What builds on what, and what makes what easier to learn?

Comment: Start by extensively learning JavaScript. These two links would help: http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html and http://yuiblog.com/crockford/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"AJAX" should not be in that list. "JSF 2.0 Ajax", "jQuery AJAX" might be, but the technique itself is at a different abstraction level. IMHO you must master it before working at anything else. It should only take some hours, and you'll get a good background.

Afterwards, Spring Core is a must. You can't get into MVC before understanding the core. Spring MVC and JSF 2.0 should come later.

Also consider a JSF library. I'd suggest RichFaces, since it's JSF 2.0 compilant and provides you a nice set of components.

Comment: Several months later, and I have gotten baseline competency in all the above technologies, except JSF (However I now understand the difference between the JSF specification and specific implementations.)  Despite being closed and down-voted, the answers were helpful.  Especially the comment about Ajax and the level of abstraction. This was my first question/post here; apologies for using the word "best"... but the key issue really was "do any of these technologies build on another in a strict-dependency manner." That's how I should have worded it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you could start with either Spring (core, not MVC) OR AJAX, as those are two different technologies.

Assuming you choose Spring, start with learning Core Spring, such as the IoC container, how to wire up beans, etc.  That will position you to learn Spring MVC as the concepts are pretty much the same.

With AJAX, it depends what you want to learn.  If it's high level concepts, a good Wikipedia article or a few blog posts is all you need.  If you want to learn how to implement an async call to a server and update a snippet of the DOM, then you could learn how to do that in jQuery, Prototype, etc.

Finally, I think you should learn JSF 2.0 after learning Spring MVC.

Hope this helps.